# Word Cloud Using Python

Tags: python-3.x, word-cloud

I want to create a word cloud with the variable 'word' that will show me the cloud of all words that are 'NN' and 'NNP'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator
# Using Textblob
for word,noun in blob.tags:
    if noun in ['NN','NNP']:
    print(f'{word} ==> {noun}')
```

where will I add the following code:

- Create and generate a word cloud image:

  ```
  wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(word)
  # Display the generated image:
  plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
  plt.axis("off")
  plt.show()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to shortlist the words and generate a list object like something below:

```
words = []
for word,noun in blob.tags:
    if noun in ['NN','NNP']:
       print(f'{word} ==> {noun}')
       words.append(word)
```

And then, you can feed the above word list into word cloud generator as below, optionally you can mention a list of stopwords:

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=STOPWORDS).generate(' '.join(words))
# Display the generated image:
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```